# Umbraco - GetMedia does not return the correct url

Tags: c#, .net, xpath, umbraco

I'm trying to redirect to the media url, but using the code blow, results in the full url concatenated by the size of the media.

So for example the url returns /media/123/example.pdfpdf4000

```
XPathNodeIterator xName = umbraco.library.GetMedia(Convert.ToInt32(pdfid), false);
string url = xName.Current.Value;
Response.Redirect("~/"+ url);
```

What is happening?

Answer (score 3):

I was just looking for how to do this, and umbraco now includes uQuery to get data like this easier, so to answer your question you could use:

```
Media pdf = umbraco.uQuery.GetMedia(pdfId);
Response.Redirect(pdf.GetProperty<string>("umbracoFile"));
```

Just a note: If it was an image media item (rather than a file) it'd be even easier:

```
Media img = umbraco.uQuery.GetMedia(imgId);
imgTag.ImageUrl = img.GetImageUrl();
```

Not sure why uQuery doesn't include `GetFileUrl()` but `GetProperty<string>()` seems nicer than using the xpath iterator yourself.

Comment: Notably (and annoyingly), `umbraco.uQuery.GetMedia` appears to return a deprecated form of the `Media` data model.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [solution explained here](http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/32147-Image-path-from-umbracolibraryGetMedia-is-wrong) and also [here](http://forum.umbraco.org/yaf_postst4929_Getmedia-in-usercontrol.aspx). But, in essence you can create a method as below to fix the issue:

```
public string getImage(int ImageID)
{
    XPathNodeIterator xn = umbraco.library.GetMedia(ImageID, false);
    xn.MoveNext();

    XPathNodeIterator xn2 = xn.Current.Select("data[@alias='umbracoFile']");
    xn2.MoveNext();
    return xn2.Current.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the media file URL, it's simply

```
new Media(mediaId).getProperty("umbracoFile").Value.ToString()
```

Comment: This isn't a valid constructor for `Media`.

Comment: Thanks for the "getProperty("umbracoFile").Value.ToString()" part. That worked for me. I'm not sure about the constructor though